# Chrome for iOS - What is a way to handle popup to parent communication?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popup, chrome-ios

Two observations when dealing with popups in Chrome for iOS:

1. Popups that are spawned inside an iframe will kill the parent window, the tab will closed, never to be seen again
2. Popups that are spawned in a non-iframe context open a new tab with the popup (expected), then when the pop-up is done with it's business it not possible to communicate back to the parent using 'window.opener'

For (2), a potential option would be to use localStorage polling in the parent window. For (1), I have yet to find a solution.

Details:

- In (1) the iframe was hosted on a HTTP site, but the content inside the iframe was HTTPS
- We have not been able to reproduce (1) or (2) in any other environment except Chrome for iOS

**Question**: What is a way to handle communication between popups and their parents in Chrome iOS without (a) killing the tab itself or (b) parent hanging around forever waiting for a response? If there's no feasibe solution that cater for these issues, then, what can I do instead?

Comment: I am having same issue on Chrome on iPhone. Popup is opened from an iframe, and it is killing itself and the parent window in which the iframe was loaded when tried to close it.

Comment: did you solve? what was the answer? @bjornl

Comment: I'm sorry - can't remember. This was almost 10 years ago